# post values with ajax, php put it in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to accept user data from a form, use AJAX to post the values to a PHP script, which will insert them into the database.

JQuery:

```
$(".add").click(function(){
    var order = {
        Name: $name.val(),
        Drink: $drink.val(),
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/api/orders.php',
        data: order,
        success: function(newOrder){
            $orders.append('<li>Name: ' + newOrder.Name +', Drink: '+ newOrder.Drink +'</li>')
    }
    })
});
```

Php:

```
 //open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxxxxx","test") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

//fetch table rows from mysql db
$sql = "select * from orders";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

$name = $_POST["Name"];
$drink = $_POST["Drink"];

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO orders (Id, Name, Drink) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$drink')";
//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
```

can somebody help me with it?

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: Apart from other issues, your code is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: you didn't query/connect to db here `$sql2 = "INSERT INTO orders (Id, Name, Drink) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$drink')";` so your INSERT never happens. *"and the php puts it in my database."* - **It won't.** @KylianWester

Comment: now who's going to *"nom nom nom"* on that? ^ and who knows if your HTML is correct.

Comment: What is the problem you have with that code ?

Comment: The problem is: he select order, update order and return orders info but without the last change. So just change the order of operations. 1. Update, 2. select 3. return set of data, And yeaaa, SQL injections

Comment: @volkinc why would that be? their 2nd query is clearly not executed.

Comment: *groan* - Here `$sql2 = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO orders (Id, Name, Drink) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$drink')") or die(mysqli_error($connection));`

Comment: where's the HTML that goes with this?? and where are we with this question? @ me if you want, I'm moving on.

Comment: //open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxxxxx","test") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

`//fetch table rows from mysql db
$sql = "select * from orders";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));` i'am connecting

Comment: not for your INSERT you're not `$sql2 = "INSERT INTO orders (Id, Name, Drink) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$drink')";` there is no indication as to where you're querying/connecting for it. I'm glad I didn't post my answer that I had lined up, because I knew that would bite me hard. Like I said earlier, that INSERT will NEVER happen, not with what you posted anyway.

Comment: I've asked you about your HTML, you didn't respond or edit your question to add it. Then I told you what you needed to use for your INSERT, still no response. Sorry to say, but I won't be staying around this question any much longer. This time I have really left this question. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should insert before you get all orders

```
$name = $_POST["Name"];
$drink = $_POST["Drink"];

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO orders (Id, Name, Drink) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$drink')";
mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or 
             die("Error in Inserting" . mysqli_error($connection))

$id = mysqli_insert_id ($connection);
$sql = "select * from orders where Id = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or 
             die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);
```

The javascript will be right this:

```
$(".add").click(function(){
    var order = {
        Name: $name.val(),
        Drink: $drink.val(),
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/api/orders.php',
        data: order,
        success: function(newOrder) {
            $.each(newOrder, function(order) {
                //$order is a ul that have id = orders
                $orders.append('<li>Name: ' + order.Name +', Drink: '+ order.Drink +'</li>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and if you need anything ask :]

**UPDATE**

please update the success function you have to this

```
        success: function(data) {
            data.forEach(function(order) {
                //$orders is a ul that have id = orders
                $orders.append('<li>Name: ' + order.Name +', Drink: '+ order.Drink +'</li>');
            });
        }
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
success: function(data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    var length = obj.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        $orders.append('<li>Name: ' + obj[i].Name +', Drink: '+ obj[i].Drink +'</li>');
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
$name = $_POST["Name"];
$drink = $_POST["Drink"];

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO orders (Id, Name, Drink) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$drink')";
mysqli_query($connection, $sql2) or 
             die("Error in Inserting" . mysqli_error($connection))

$id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
$sql = "select * from orders where Id = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or 
             die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);
```

Comment: i get an error in the console "newOrder.each is not a function"

Comment: @KylianWester  please let me see the result of console.log(newOrder);

Comment: i get "newOrder is not defined", i'am learing al this, so it's a dumb thing i think XD

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"Id":"1","Name":"kylian","Drink":"Coffee"},{"Id":"2","Name":"Chris","Drink":"Tea"},{"Id":"3","Name":"Jelle","Drink":"Coffee"},{"Id":"4","Name":"Ruud","Drink":"IceTea"}]` i get this console error

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function`

Comment: @KylianWester check update 2 please i hope this work :)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined` nope

Comment: @KylianWester that was my mistake please change **order[i].Name** to **obj[i].Name** and **order[i].Drink** to **obj[i].Drink** as it is in the update 2 right i edit it to make it right.

Comment: @KylianWester you need the last one only ??? let me update the code, see update 3 i thought that you need all results after insert.